# How to add tab to CustomApplication on parent managed package

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have a managed package in the Salesforce app exchange and I am beginning to develop "add on" managed packages as well that all have dependencies on the original managed package. I was wondering if it was possible to add new tabs on the original Managed Package's `CustomApplication` whenever an "add on" package was installed.

For example, lets say that when the Original Managed Package is installed, a `CustomApplication` is created with 3 tabs (Home, Setup, SomeCustomTab). But when `Add On Package 1` is installed, I want to automatically add a tab to the custom application so that it has 4 tabs (Home, Setup, SomeCustomTab, and Add On Package 1 Config).

This seems like something that should be possible, however I'm not able to find any resources on how to make it happen. Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: We do this by providing whole new apps in the different packages. Typically the extensions we have are integrations with other packages, so the app wants to include tabs from both (plus some specific to the integration).

Comment: @PhilW that makes a lot of sense. In this case, the extension is a really small feature (just a few flow enabled LWC's, and a custom object). I wanted to automatically add the custom object and fields to the permission sets that are generated by the "main" package, and I figured that the best way to do that would just be to add a simple "setup" tab in the main Custom App that just has a button that uses the Financial Force MetadataService which can update the permission sets. Do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: I would be tempted to simply provide an additional permission set and instruction to add that to a relevant perm set group. Sometimes less is more...

Comment: @PhilW Yeah that sounds like a much simpler solution, I think I'll go with that one! Thank you!